# Lazy loading knockoutjs with bookmarklet failing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bookmarklet, asana

I'm attempting to fix a bookmarklet I wrote to track the URL changes in a single page application, specifically recording timesheet while using asana. It uses a script loader to embed jQuery and KnockoutJS libraries before init. I'm unable to find the `ko` object in global scope after the KnockoutJS library has initialized and cannot figure out why. To test, login to https://app.asana.com, open the Google Chrome developer tools' Console tab and try the following code:

```
var koScript=document.createElement('script');
koScript.type='text/javascript';
koScript.src='//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(koScript);
```

The Network tab shows the script downloading. The Elements tab shows the script as the last child of the head element. Yet `ko` remains undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that:

1. Asana uses an internal module system that uses `module.exports` and `require` - the CommonJS standard you may know from node.js.
2. The `knockout.js` file checks the environment to determine if it should be setting `window.ko` or using `module.exports` or AMD-style `define`. If it detects CommonJS-style `require` it sets properties on `exports` instead of on a global `ko` object.

Workaround:

You could temporarily "copy" require off first:

```
_require = require; require = null
```

And then it should set `window.ko` as you're expecting!

Comment: Thanks dude, that makes perfect sense. Following that logic in knockoutjs, module.exports is now set to the ko object I'm expecting, right? So I could potentially `window['ko'] = module.exports;` to get it back...

Comment: Yeah, but `module.exports` might conceivably contain other things as well at that point. It might not right now, but if you really want to guarantee a clean `ko` object, I'd really recommend either the approach above, or something like `module.exports = window['ko'] = {}; <load script>; module.exports = exports;` or something.